# How to get user location name?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm using javascript function to get user latitude and longitude using google map api.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
            var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
            var lon = pos.coords.longitude;
        });
    });
```

does any one know how to get location name instead of latitude and longitude? for example Beverly Hills, California

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Google Maps API's Geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding). You can pass in the `latlng` to the geocode request, and in the callback expect the data of the address.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': currentLocation }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        //the `results` variable will be an array with formatted addresses and location details
    }
});
```